# Debugging on an Android device after first release

Tags: android, eclipse

Now that my android app is released on the google app store, I would like to continue developing and debugging on the device.

I have a few options:

1. Delete the app from the device and install a new version during development.

   - This has disadvantages. I lose the local files saved with the released app, and, when the time comes for the next release, I do not share the same experience as my users while upgrading.
2. Introduce a minimal change by, say, renaming the package. The two apps are now distinct and can co-exist on the device.

   - This introduces a superfluous change in the souce tree, with all the headaches that that entails.

If you have avoided these difficulties, what approach have you taken when you continued to develop after release?

Comment: you just continue developing like you did, no matter your app is being published or not. You only should take care about things that relies to debug or release fingerprints.

Comment: What are "the headaches" that result from the package name change?  (other than the fact that that, too, loses your local files.

Comment: A similar problem is creating a paid and a free version based on the same code base. I usually solve that by creating an Android library project that contains everything common to both versions (including activities, resources, etc.) and two Android app projects for the paid and the free version which reference that library. They both specify different package names in the manifest file so they can coexist on one device. You could do the same by creating a debug project with a different package name.

Comment: Another issue is: if you want to debug the upgrade process (database changes for example), you're going to risk data loss anyway. Create backups of your app data files before testing an upgrade.

Comment: What build system do you use? Certainly with Maven (and probably with Gradle) it is possible to change the package name at compile time so you can install as many copies of the same app as you want, without any source changes.

Comment: **"I do not share the same experience as my users while upgrading."** - Why not? Before I publish a new release I remove my debug version from my devices, download the current release from Google Play then push my new release version out using bluetooth or FTP. I then see the same upgrade experience as my current users will. If I'm happy it worked as it should I then publish the new release to Google Play.

Comment: If you are going to be changing keys, say between debug and release, and you have local app data you care about, you'll probably need to make a version which adds an export/import capability for that data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and [Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).  Using build types (which I can't link to because I am a n00b and have no reputation), you can easily switch between debug and release builds, and set up your build file to have both on your device at the same time without changing anything in your source or manifest.

The one big gotcha that I failed to understand and bit me in the butt several times until I got it is that in the Build Variants tool window, the selected build variant controls everything.  If you choose the release variant:

- when you build, it will build an APK with your release keys (if you've set them up in the build files)
- when you run the app, it will put the release version on your device
- if you try to debug the app, the debugger will not attach because the app is not debuggable

And of course all the reverse if you select the debug build variant.

You have to give up Eclipse, which if you're like me is a sad thing, but I've heard they're planning to add Gradle support to Eclipse at some point.

Comment: I would never ever use a technology preview tool for production (even if it is quite good already).

Comment: That is a good consideration.  It depends on a lot of things whether it may be a good idea for you or not.  Personally I think the bugs are far more likely to be in the IDE part of the tool rather than the build part, in other words the app could crash or the UI not do quite what it's supposed to, but is not likely to produce an incorrect APK.  Google has a history of calling products "beta" when they've been in widespread use by the public for a long time, so you could be waiting a long time for them to call it a finished product.  It also has different build channels with varying stability.